# Number (Error) A mapped function's arguments cannot be used in client-side operations

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to calculate fractional vegetation. After loading Landsat collections and calculating NDVI, I created following function. However, following error occurs when I run this function.

Is there any possible solution for this?

```
function addfv(img) {
// find the min and max of NDVI
  var min = ee.Number(img.select('NDVI').reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
  }).values().get(0));
  print(min, 'min');

  var max = ee.Number(img.select('NDVI').reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
  }).values().get(0));
  print(max, 'max');

//fractional vegetation
  var fv =(img.select('NDVI').subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min))).pow(ee.Number(2)).rename('FV'); 
  print(fv, 'fv');
  return img.addBands(fv)
  
}

col = col.map(addfv);
print ('col fv', col)
```

> Number (Error) A mapped function's arguments cannot be used in client-side operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print()` statements are client side functions and thus can not be used in mapped functions.

If you remove all your calls to print within the `addfv()` function, everything should work.